# Prefixref instruction found in mscorlib

Tags: .net, cil

***TL;DR:*** What is Prefixref? Can it play about with argument/instruction lengths?

---

I've been working on a .NET binary parsing tool recently and, when testing my library on bits of mscorlib, I started getting some odd exceptions where IL wasn't behaving (branching into arguments!). I have investigated and have tracked my problem down to System.Random.InternalSample (a method that doesn't appear in ildasm). I have gerryrigged my binary analyser to produce ILDASM-like output and the following is what it produces for this mysterious function (comments were added manually).

The bit i can't figure out is what is happening at `IL_0044`. This instruction seems to branch into the middle of another operation! Either I'm reading the CIL very wrong, there is something very odd going on here or those pletyful prefixref instructions are confusing things. Does anyone have any idea what prefixref is? The documentation simply says it's reserved and 'not intended to be used directly from your code.'

```
.maxstack 3
.locals init (  [0] System.Int32 V_0,
                [1] System.Int32 V_1,
                [2] System.Int32 V_2)
IL_0000:    ldarg_0 
IL_0001:    ldfld   0xB5 0x05 0x00 0x04 
IL_0006:    stloc_1 
IL_0007:    ldarg_0 
IL_0008:    ldfld   0xB6 0x05 0x00 0x04 
IL_000D:    stloc_2 
IL_000E:    ldloc_1 
IL_000F:    ldc_i4_1    
IL_0010:    add 
IL_0011:    dup 
IL_0012:    stloc_1 
IL_0013:    ldc_i4_s    0x38 
IL_0015:    blt_s   0x02 // IL_0019 
IL_0017:    ldc_i4_1    
IL_0018:    stloc_1 
IL_0019:    ldloc_2 
IL_001A:    ldc_i4_1    
IL_001B:    add 
IL_001C:    dup 
IL_001D:    stloc_2 
IL_001E:    ldc_i4_s    0x38 
IL_0020:    blt_s   0x02 // IL_0024
IL_0022:    ldc_i4_1    
IL_0023:    stloc_2 
IL_0024:    ldarg_0 
IL_0025:    ldfld   0xB7 0x05 0x00 0x04 
IL_002A:    ldloc_1 
IL_002B:    ldelem_i4   
IL_002C:    ldarg_0 
IL_002D:    ldfld   0xB7 0x05 0x00 0x04 
IL_0032:    ldloc_2 
IL_0033:    ldelem_i4   
IL_0034:    sub 
IL_0035:    stloc_0 
IL_0036:    ldloc_0 
IL_0037:    ldc_i4_m1   
IL_0038:    prefixref   
IL_0039:    prefixref   
IL_003A:    prefixref   
IL_003B:    ldsflda 0x33 0x04 0x06 0x17 
IL_0040:    sub 
IL_0041:    stloc_0 
IL_0042:    ldloc_0 
IL_0043:    ldc_i4_0    
IL_0044:    bge_s   0x08 // IL_004B + 0x03
IL_0046:    ldloc_0 
IL_0047:    ldc_i4_m1   
IL_0048:    prefixref   
IL_0049:    prefixref   
IL_004A:    prefixref   
IL_004B:    ldsflda 0x58 0x0A 0x02 0x7B 
IL_0050:    conv_ovf_i4 
IL_0051:    ldarg_3 
IL_0052:    nop 
IL_0053:    ldarg_2 
IL_0054:    ldloc_1 
IL_0055:    ldloc_0 
IL_0056:    stelem_i4   
IL_0057:    ldarg_0 
IL_0058:    ldloc_1 
IL_0059:    stfld   0xB5 0x05 0x00 0x04 
IL_005E:    ldarg_0 
IL_005F:    ldloc_2 
IL_0060:    stfld   0xB6 0x05 0x00 0x04 
IL_0065:    ldloc_0 
IL_0066:    ret
```

Comment: It is not a mysterious method, do compare your output against a known-to-work one like ildasm.exe, ILSpy or Reflector.  Your code appears to go completely haywire around IL_0037, impossible to guess why.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant, Thank you for your response. I've found my parser to produce identical output to ILDASM on other functions, this is the first function I have found a problem with. Do you have any information about the `InternalSample` method?

Comment: It is above all not mysterious because [its source code is readily available](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,dec894a7e816e665).  Well, you are not using that version.  This is not going to help you diagnose the bug in your code.  As long as you don't show it you'll have to spend more time with the debugger.  You have a very specific "it goes wrong here" target to focus on.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the link. Tracing through the source found the problem - there was a default to -1 somewhere in the bowels of my code which produced the ldc.i4.m1 where it should have been ldc.i4 followed by 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x7F (max int). If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as best answer.